# WPF installation path Variable? where are my installation files

Tags: c#

I utilized install shield to create an installer for my program, while I was working out of visual studios i created many needed files in a folder on my desktop, this folder is now inside of the path being installed to.

Is there a way to refference the current installation path? Example :  Get icon from Environment.InstallationPath   ,  or something to that effect? Like how can i reference my installation folder without writing up a long string path assuming the folder exists?

Comment: Are you wanting to do this in the installer or in your WPF application when the user runs it?

Comment: After it is installed certain buttons should reach into this resources folder for needed links, xmls etc
Resources folder is INstallationPath\resourcesFolder

Comment: Again, is this needed inside the InstallShield installer or inside the WPF application? You say after it is installed but that could mean after installation on the last page of the installer or when the user runs the application after installation. Please be as clear as possible.

Comment: Sorry, When the user runs the application, the nature of the application is to consistently fetch resources from this folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will give you the folder in which the WPF application resides, which will be the location it was installed to.

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

You will need to include the following namespaces

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
```

You can also do something like this

```
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Resources");
```

Comment: Thank you!
as far as accessing these resources for XAML markup, is there a variable I can utilize? for example if i have a picture that i need to source from this folder?  thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, you can do this with packed URIs. Here is a link to the MSDN documentation for it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx There are a lot of different things you can do with it but basically it's a string that goes in your image's source attribute.